# How to use a sorted list as a filter?

Tags: python

I want to get all `oneKmer`s that don't exist in `in.txt`.
`in.txt` is sorted in the same order as `oneKmer` at column 0.

It should be doable in O(N) instead of O(N^2) since both lists are in the same order.

How can I write this ?

```py
import csv
import itertools

tsvfile = open('in.txt', "r")
tsvreader = csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter=" ")

for i in itertools.product('ACTG', repeat = 18):
    oneKmer = ''.join(i)
    flag = 1
    with open(InFile) as tsvfile:
        tsvreader = csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter=" ")
        for line in tsvreader:
            if line[0] == oneKmer:
                flag = 0
                break
    if flag:
        print(oneKmer)
```

`in.txt`:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 1400100
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC 37055
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAT 70686
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAG 192363
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACA 20042
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACC 12965
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACT 10596
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACG 1732
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATA 16440
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATC 18461
...
```

The whole `in.txt` file is 38,569,002,592 bytes with 1,836,020,688 lines.

The expected result should be (4^18 - 1,836,020,688) lines of strings. Of course I will further filter them later in the script.

---

For an easy example, say I want to print the integers <16 that don't exist in a given sorted list `[3,5,6,8,10,11]`. The result should be `[1,2,4,7,9,12,13,14,15]`. The given list is huge, so I want to read it one element at a time. So when I read 3, I know I can print out 1 and 2. Then skip 3, and read the next 5, now I can print out 4 and skip 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few solutions, all processing the supersequence and the subsequence in parallel, taking linear time and constant memory.

Using your easy example:

```
full = iter(range(1, 16))
skip = iter([3,5,6,8,10,11])
```

Solution 0: (the one I came up with last, but should've done first)

```
s = next(skip, None)
for x in full:
    if x == s:
        s = next(skip, None)
    else:
        print(x)
```

Solution 1:

```
from heapq import merge
from itertools import groupby

for x, g in groupby(merge(full, skip)):
    if len(list(g)) == 1:
        print(x)
```

Solution 2:

```
for s in skip:
    for x in iter(full.__next__, s):
        print(x)
for x in full:
    print(x)
```

Solution 3:

```
from functools import partial

until = partial(iter, full.__next__)
for s in skip:
    for x in until(s):
        print(x)
for x in full:
    print(x)
```

Solution 4:

```
from itertools import takewhile

for s in skip:
    for x in takewhile(s.__ne__, full):
        print(x)
for x in full:
    print(x)
```

Output of all solutions:

```
1
2
4
7
9
12
13
14
15
```

Solution 0 for your actual problem:

```
import csv
import itertools

with open('in.txt') as tsvfile:
    tsvreader = csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter=' ')
    skip = next(tsvreader, [None])[0]
    for i in itertools.product('ACTG', repeat=18):
        oneKmer = ''.join(i)
        if oneKmer == skip:
            skip = next(tsvreader, [None])[0]
        else:
            print(oneKmer)
```

Slight variation:

```
import csv
from itertools import product
from operator import itemgetter

with open('in.txt') as tsvfile:
    tsvreader = csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter=' ')
    skips = map(itemgetter(0), tsvreader)
    skip = next(skips, None)
    for oneKmer in map(''.join, product('ACTG', repeat=18)):
        if oneKmer == skip:
            skip = next(skips, None)
        else:
            print(oneKmer)
```

Comment: Would you tell me which methods can be used with `csv.reader` without load the whole file ? I am not familiar with python.

Comment: And, which methods are cycling both list once ? Are they all cycling once ?

Comment: @Galaxy All of them. I just edited, made `full` and `skip` iterators.

Comment: @Galaxy And now I just added the simplest solution, that I should've started with :-)

Comment: Will Solution 1-4 methods loads the whole list into memory ? I am not sure whether python will do sth. like lazy copy or not.

Comment: @Galaxy No, they all properly treat them as iterators. See new edit at the bottom of the answer, showing code for your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, opening files many times cases slow so ACTG loop must be included in file loop. Second, Stdout is slow than you think, so stop `print(onemake)` and output to file directly. They must improve speed possibly.